# Convert 24 Hour Time Date Object into 12 Hour Time Date Object

Tags: ios, swift, date-formatting

I'm simply trying to turn a Date object when a user has "24 hour time" enabled on their iPhone into a "12 hour time" Date Object.

I've tried this as stated in previous threads regarding this issue, but I've had no luck:

**Initial finalDate object**: Date  2017-08-30 22:00:00 UTC

```
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier:"en_US")
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"
 let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: finalDate)
 let theFinalConvertedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

**What I end up with:**

```
    theFinalConvertedDate   Date? 2017-08-30 22:00:00 UTC
```

I am not sure why this is happening considering that dateString prints out to be:

```
"08/30/2017 5:00 PM"
```

So it does initially convert it to the expected output, but theFinalConvertedDate ends up being  Date? 2017-08-30 22:00:00 UTC

Comment: As others have said, no `Date` conversion is needed, as `Date` objects don't have "24 hour" vs "12 hour" format. It's solely a question of how you want the `DateFormatter` output string formatted. But what is the purpose of this `theFinalConvertedDate` string? Is it for presenting in the UI or for sending to a web service or some local persistent storage? The correct answer to this question depends upon what the ultimate usage of this string is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense whatsoever to attempt to change the format of a `Date` object. A `Date` has no format. You only get a string in some desired format by using `DateFormat` to convert the `Date` to a `String`.

Logging a `Date` always shows the date value in the UTC timezone with a fixed format.

All you need is:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier:"en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: finalDate)
```

`dateString` is the value you care about. This will be in the desired format.

And note that you need to use `en_US_POSIX` to ensure the result isn't affected by the user's time settings on the iOS device.

Comment: rmaddy, I know you know this, but I mention it for the sake of future readers: Only use `en_US_POSIX` locale if the purpose of the string is for interacting with web service and/or persistent storage. If presenting the date to the end user, this would be a very bad idea. But if for web service or persistent storage, then using `en_US_POSIX` is excellent approach (but if that were the case, the choice of this `MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a` format vs ISO 8601/RFC 3999 is very weird).

Comment: @Rob To add to that, I would state that for any date/time being shown to the user, you should rarely use `dateFormat`. You should use some desired combination of `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`.